# MVC ASP.NET Core vista uno-muchos

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

La pregunta es: ¿Cómo mostrar en un *View* de *MVC ASP.NET Core*, una relación de uno a muchos?

En mi caso, tengo la entidad cabecera del sistema, llamada **Conferencia**. Sus entidades dependientes directas, son las **Divisiones** que hasta ahora son cuatro `[0,1,2,3]`, y tiene dos puestos de trabajo registrados, el *Director* y la *Secretaria*, aunque todavía no se han vinculado quienes ostentarán estos cargos.

La instrucción es la siguiente:

```
var viewModel = _context.Conferencia.Include(c => c.División).Include(c => c.PuestoGC)
```

Como será evidente, la conferencia es una con 4 (muchas) divisiones, y con dos (muchos) cargos, por el otro lado.

El propósito es mostrar en un *View*, la *Conferencia* y debajo el *Listado* de *Divisiones*, y debajo de ambas, el *Listado* de los *Puestos*. El problema es que en el *View*, nos es posible extraer solo los datos de la *Conferencia*, y a pesar de que podemos ver los datos de las *Divisiones* y los *Puestos* en el *ViewModel*, **No sabemos cómo obtener sus ítemes para mostrarlos**.

La imagen de abajo, muestra lo que vemos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Has probado con un for o foreach anidados?

Comment: Oh, Muchas Gracias, Eslacuare, gracias por ayudarnos a dar este paso.